# JavaFX. Удаление строк из TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, удаление

Всем доброго дня!
Есть следующий кусок кода, описывающий структуру TreeTableView:

```
void FillTable(TreeTableView<Task> taskTable) throws SQLException {
    DbHandler dbHandler = new DbHandler();
    //Заполнение списка задач из базы данных
    ObservableList<Task> taskList;
    try{
        taskList = dbHandler.getAllProducts();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        taskList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

//Список корневых задач
    ObservableList<Task> rootTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//Список дочерних задач
    ObservableList<Task> childrenTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //Разделение задач на корневые и дочерние
    for (Task task : taskList)
    {
       if (task.getRootTask()) rootTasks.add(task);
       else childrenTasks.add(task);
    }
    //Присвоение дочерних задач к своим корневым задачам (по идентификатору задачи)
    TreeItem<Task>startItem = new TreeItem<Task>();
    for (Task task : rootTasks)
    {
        Integer idTask = task.getIdTask();
        TreeItem<Task> rootTreeItem = new TreeItem<Task>(task);
        for (Task children : childrenTasks)
        {
            if (children.getIdTask() == idTask)
            {
                TreeItem<Task> childrenTreeItem = new TreeItem<Task>(children);
                rootTreeItem.getChildren().add(childrenTreeItem);
            }
        }
        startItem.getChildren().add(rootTreeItem);
    }
    taskTable.setRoot(startItem);
    taskTable.setShowRoot(false);
    }
```

Не могу нигде найти, как можно удалить строку из такой структуры и вообще какую-либо информацию по удалению строк из TreeTableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, который непосредственно удаляет запись, помещён внутри обработчика нажатия на кнопку "Удалить".

```
deleteBtn.setOnAction(action -> {

    var selection = treeTable.getSelectionModel();
    var index = selection.getSelectedIndex();

    if (index > -1) {
        var selectedItem = treeTable.getTreeItem(index);
        selectedItem.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedItem);
        selection.clearSelection();
        deletionInfo.setValue("Удалено: " + selectedItem.getValue().toString());
    } else {
        deletionInfo.setValue("");
    }

});
```

Весь код.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class TreeTableViewApp extends Application {

    private final StringProperty deletionInfo = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private record Task(Integer id, String task) {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        var treeTable = new TreeTableView<Task>();
        fillTreeTable(treeTable);

        var deleteBtn = new Button("Удалить");

        deleteBtn.setOnAction(action -> {

            var selection = treeTable.getSelectionModel();
            var index = selection.getSelectedIndex();

            if (index > -1) {
                var selectedItem = treeTable.getTreeItem(index);
                selectedItem.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedItem);
                selection.clearSelection();
                deletionInfo.setValue("Удалено: " + selectedItem.getValue().toString());
            } else {
                deletionInfo.setValue("");
            }

        });

        var lastDeletionLabel = new Label();
        lastDeletionLabel.setFont(Font.font(10));
        lastDeletionLabel.textProperty().bind(deletionInfo);

        var group = new HBox(12, lastDeletionLabel, deleteBtn);
        group.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        group.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        var root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(treeTable, group);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void fillTreeTable(TreeTableView<Task> tableView) {

        var idColumn = new TreeTableColumn<Task, String>("Номер");
        idColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        var taskColumn = new TreeTableColumn<Task, String>("Задание");

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                cellData.getValue().getValue().id().toString()
        ));
        taskColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                cellData.getValue().getValue().task()
        ));
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(List.of(idColumn, taskColumn));

        var rootItem = new TreeItem<Task>();
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(getContent());
        tableView.setRoot(rootItem);
        tableView.setShowRoot(false);

    }

    private List<TreeItem<Task>> getContent() {

        var drawFigures = new TreeItem<>(new Task(100, "Нарисовать фигуры"));
        drawFigures.getChildren().addAll(List.of(
                new TreeItem<>(new Task(101, "Овал")),
                new TreeItem<>(new Task(102, "Треугольник"))
        ));

        var drawAnimals = new TreeItem<>(new Task(200, "Нарисовать животных"));
        drawAnimals.getChildren().addAll(List.of(
                new TreeItem<>(new Task(201, "Птица")),
                new TreeItem<>(new Task(202, "Ёж"))
        ));

        return List.of(drawFigures, drawAnimals);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```